# Use the value of an active cell to hyperlink (or VBA) to the same value on another sheet in same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am a fairly advanced excel user, but limited experience in VBA coding; can anyone give me a hand, or start me in the right direction please?

I have two sheets with tables:

The first (MASTER) sheet has product information which includes a unique stock code (SKU); it also identifies the SKU of any product which can be used as a substitute for that first product as a separate column entry.  Both the product details of the MASTER product and the potential SUBSTITUTE product are in this MASTER sheet table.

The second (SUBSTITUTE) sheet is filtered to show the products which have potential substitutes along with the SKU of that potential substitute. It gets this information from the MASTER sheet and table.

I want to be able to select the potential substitute SKU cell on the SUBSTITUTE sheet, and then either hyperlink or use VBA to use that value to jump to the cell in the MASTER sheet that has that same value as that in the SUBSTITUTE’s cell.

In summary the pseudo code is:

1. Go to SUBSTITUTE worksheet
2. Position/select on a SKU code in the table
3. THE CODING WOULD START HERE. (VBA OR HYPERLINK)
4. Get that cell’s value and store as a variable
5. JUMP to MASTER worksheet
6. Find the value of the variable in the SKU column (SKUs are unique)
7. Make that cell with the same valu as the variable the active cell

Is it do-able?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terry, the macro below may take care of most of your needs. You can create a keyboard shortcut for this macro and each time you run the macro, it will search for the text in the (SUBSTITUTE-sheet) cell you selected, in the `MASTER` sheet in your excel file and will show it to you.  After that you can manually change the data or you can edit macro according to your needs.  See sample screenshots below.

```
Sub Macro4()
    my_text = Selection.Value
    Sheets("MASTER").Activate
    Cells.Select
    On Error GoTo my_err
    Selection.Find(What:=my_text, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Exit Sub
my_err: MsgBox "search text not found"
        Sheets("SUBSTITUTE").Select
    
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Terry, my answer above is kind of a ready-to-use solution to your problem. For your possible future queries, I recommend you to start coding in VBA.  A good way to start could be recording a macro in excel and then analysing the codes in the macro.

Comment: How to start briefly: Click on record macro button in developer toolbar, perform your copy/paste/find/delete/etc operations, then stop your macro. Then hit Alt + F8, select your macro and click on edit. Analyse the codes excel recorded and try to improve them according to your needs (i.e. if you will use it regularly, make adjustments accordingly. You will need to define variables/constants/arrays and get to know software things like do loop, for next, if then etc.). When you got stuck you can do a quick google search and after all if you still need help, you can ask another question here.

Comment: Thanks so much.  The problem with this is that if finds the data which includes the column in the  Master spreadsheet that has the "SUBSTITUTE" code. I just want it to look up a range in the "C" column. I tried using "Range,Find" and then AFTER:=RANGE"C1:C999") bur I get a compile error, "Argument Not Optional" - what am I missing?

This is what I have for that part of the code:
Range.Find(What:=my_text, After:=Range("C1:C999"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
       LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Comment: To look up a range in the "C" column, just replace the line `Cells.Select` with `Columns("C:C").Select` in the original macro I gave before.

Comment: Thanks again:  The problem with learning a new language is that you "Don't know, what you don't know"  Trying to look up something you don't know exist (search by column) proved t be a bit of a challenge.  Again, Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Activate Cell on Another Worksheet

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- This runs automatically (on its own), there's nothing to run manually.
- When you select a `SKU` cell in the `Substitute` worksheet, it activates the cell containing the same `SKU` value in the `Master` worksheet making it the top-most and left-most cell (modify if necessary).

**Sheet Module e.g. `Substitute`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    SelectSKU Target
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SelectSKU(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    ' Source
    Const shRow As Long = 1
    Const sTitle As String = "SKU"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Master"
    Const dhRow As Long = 1
    Const dTitle As String = "SKU"
    
    ' Source
    
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    If shRow < 1 Then Exit Sub ' Source Header Row too small
    If shRow >= ws.Rows.Count Then Exit Sub ' Source Header Row too great
    
    Dim shCell As Range: Set shCell = RefHeader(ws, sTitle, shRow)
    If shCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' Source Header not found
    
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = RefColumn(shCell.Offset(1))
    If scrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' Source Range is empty
    
    Dim sCell As Range: Set sCell = Intersect(Target.Cells(1), scrg)
    If sCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' cell not in Source Range
    If IsError(sCell) Then Exit Sub ' cell contains an error
    If Len(sCell.Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' cell is blank i.e. no SKU value
    
    Dim sValue As String: sValue = CStr(sCell.Value)
    
    ' Destination
    
    If dhRow < 1 Then Exit Sub ' Destination Header Row too small
    If dhRow >= ws.Rows.Count Then Exit Sub ' Destination Header Row too great
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = RefWorksheet(ws.Parent, dName)
    If dws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' Destination Worksheet not found
    
    Dim dhCell As Range: Set dhCell = RefHeader(dws, dTitle, dhRow)
    If dhCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' Destination Header not found
    
    Dim dcrg As Range: Set dcrg = RefColumn(dhCell.Offset(1))
    If scrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' Destination Range is empty
    
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dcrg.Find(sValue, _
        dcrg.Cells(dcrg.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    If dcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' SKU not found in Destination Range
    
    dws.Activate
    dcell.Activate
    
    ' Optional. Remove or modify one or both if you don't like it.
    With ActiveWindow
        .ScrollRow = dcell.Row
        .ScrollColumn = dcell.Column
    End With
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a row ('HeaderRow') of a worksheet ('ws'), creates
'               a reference to the first cell whose value is equal
'               to a string ('Title'). Case-insensitive.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefHeader( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal Title As String, _
    Optional ByVal HeaderRow As Long = 1) _
As Range
    If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If HeaderRow < 1 Then Exit Function
    If HeaderRow > ws.Rows.Count Then Exit Function
    With ws.Rows(HeaderRow)
        Set RefHeader = .Find(Title, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    End With
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('rg') through the bottom-most non-empty cell.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Range
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    With rg.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      In a workbook ('wb'), creates a reference to the worksheet
'               named after a string ('WorksheetName').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefWorksheet( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal WorksheetName As String) _
As Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RefWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I worked with the first set of code that was kindly sent by Ozgun and it does exactly what is needed!  Many thanks for the work