# How do I ask VBA to go to that column based on other cell value

Tags: excel, vba

my current code is hardcoded and I am not sure how to refer to the cell, based on other cells. This is my current code:

```
Dim last as long
Dim i as long
last = Worksheets("Supermarket").Cells(Rows.Count("A").End(xlUp).row
ReDim UniqueID(0 to last) as String

If ws.Range("V4") <> "" Then
For i = 0 To last
    UniqueID(i) = Worksheets("Supermarket").Range("Q2").Offset(i,0).Value             'Not always in Q2, need refer to ws
Next i
```

On ws, there is a row with column name for Supermarket (Cell V3), there is also a row with the column position for Supermarket (Cell V4).

[image]

Comment: I may recommend you something but before that can you pls tell me how do you reach to result 17 in V3.

Comment: Using named ranges can be a good option.

Comment: @OzgunSenyuva, I'm using Index Match

Comment: I will recommend something different.  At the end of the day you want to find a column named "apple" in another sheet and directly go there.  Take a look at my answer to this question which I believe is useful for you after a few adjustments:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68885171/12700614

Comment: Also, I am facing another issue
`Dim last As Long`

`last = Worksheets("Supermarket").Cells(,ws.Range("V4").Value) .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row`
`Worksheets("Supermarket").Range("B2:B") & lastRow.Copy`

How do I change my copy statement to non-hard coded?

Comment: @OzgunSenyuva, great! Thanks! I will try it out